# What do the characters in the bash environment variable $- mean?

Tags: linux, bash

I've been looking through some of the .bashrc and .profile scripts that come with various Linux distros and am seeing that sometimes they check `$-`.

Here's one in Ubuntu

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
    *) return;;
esac
```

In this case it's checking for the "i" flag is present to see if the current shell is an interactive one.

My current session gives me this :

```
# echo $-
himBH
```

What are the other flags/options mean? Is there a comprehensive list somewhere?

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

Comment: You _did_ read the man page for the bash command, didn't you?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> -
>
> Expands to the current option flags as specified upon invocation, by the [set builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) command, or those set by the shell itself (such as the -i option).

So these are the current options that control the behavior of the shell. In particular:

- `h`: Cache location of binaries in the `$PATH`. Speeds up execution, but fails if you move binaries around during the shell session.
- `i`: The current shell is interactive
- `m`: [Job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html#Job-Control) is enabled
- `B`: [Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) is enabled
- `H`: [History substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction) like `!-1`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I must have missed it somehow -_-. The `set builtin` link is very helpful.

Comment: I'm on the Bash man page right now and I didn't realize the asterisks are wildcards haha `*i*`, therefore `himBH` satisfies `*i*`

Answer (score 1):

They mean various things. Each letter corresponds to an option being set for bash. eg, "i" means that the shell is interactive (so the code sample you gave is a test to see if it's an interactive shell or not).

A full list is available in the bash man page. Look for "set" - here's the first line:

```
set [+abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [+o option-name] [arg ...]
```